# Word wrap greedy method

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a programm that uses the greedy method in order to wrap a text.The point is that we don't know the width of the line(otherwise we would use the default which is 80).Any ideas?I post the code below to see what i've done so far

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define width 80
int main(void)
{
    int ch,m;
    ch=getchar();
    while(ch!=EOF)
    {
        while ( ch!= ' ' )
        {
               putchar(ch);
               m=m+1;
               ch=getchar();
        }
            if(m>width)
        {
            printf("\n");
            m=0;
        }
        ch=getchar();


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Any ideas?" is not a very specific question.

Comment: Any suggestions?:p My code isn't right of course and i need a litle bit help in order to proceed...

Comment: If you don't know how wide the line is, you can't tell when to wrap.  To wrap, you must know how wide the line is, or deem that you know the width (assume a width).  Your code will overshoot the width, perhaps dramatically.  If someone puts a 64-character sequence with no spaces and it starts at position 64, then you'll write to position 128 on the line.  As long as that's what you intend, it isn't a problem. It may not be all that useful, but that's a separate discussion. For whatever width you use, you will need to consider what to do (if anything) with 'words' that are longer than the line.

Comment: I guess you mean you don't know the *input* width. The general idea is to scan one 'word' (space and newline separated) ahead, and emit a `\n` when you hit the width, and a space otherwise, followed by the just-scanned word

Comment: Yeah exactly,i don't know the input width.You mean to use the fgets() function?

Answer (score 1):

I tried something like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main (int argc , char **argv)
{
int i=0,capacity,ch,size=0,temp=0,metr=0;
for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
{
    atoi(argv[i]); 
    if(i==1)
    capacity=atoi(argv[i]);
}
printf("%d" , capacity);
if(capacity <=0)
{
    printf("ERROR wrong input");
    return 1;
}

char *data_tmp = NULL;
char *p = malloc(capacity * sizeof(char));
if (p == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("ERROR");
    return 1;
}
    ch=getchar();
    while (ch!= EOF) 
    {
        if (ch == '\0')
            printf("Encoding problem");
            p[size++] = ch;
            metr=metr+1;
        if (size == capacity) 
        {
        capacity += capacity;
        data_tmp = realloc(p, capacity * sizeof(char));
        if (data_tmp == NULL)
            printf("Malloc problem");
        }

        if (metr==capacity)
        printf(" \n");
        metr=0;



    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to read a line of unknown size you can go for dynamic memory allocation method.

1. Use `malloc()` allocate some memory initially and start reading your input character by character.
2. Keep increasing the size of your allocate memory using `realloc()` until a newline character is encountered.

Assuming this is what you intend to do.(Storing an unknown size line which the user has inputted)